# Add a textinput which does not belong to the same model in yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I have a table production with 3 fields productname,batchno,qty. The data productname,batchno I get is from productbatch model. I can insert it clearly. Now I want to insert into table "bottle" with 3 fields bottlename, productname, qty. Productname has relation with bottlename. And the data comes from model productnames. I want to load bottlename whenever I select productname. I can populate the data and can see in firebug. What I want is to add a textinput in the production form and display the bottlename in the same form.

Production Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Production();
        $productname = new Productnames();
        $bottle = new Bottle();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $productname->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $model->save();
            //$bottle->attributes = $model->attributes;
            $bottle->usedate = $model->productiondate;
            $bottle->useqty = $model->prodqty;
            $bottle->productname = $model->productname;
            $bottle->bottlename = $productname->bottletype;
            // $employee->emp_email = $model->emp_email;
            // $employee->emp_mobile = $model->emp_mobile;
            $bottle->save();
            return $this->redirect(['create']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'bottle' => $bottle,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Production _form

```
<div class="production-form">


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <!--<?= Html::a('Select Product', ['/production/productbatch/index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?> -->

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productiondate')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        // inline too, not bad
         'inline' => false, 
         // modify template for custom rendering
        //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
    ]);?>

    <!-- echo CHtml::button("(+)",array('title'=>"Select Product",'onclick'=>'js:selectproductforproduction();')); -->   

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product Name', 'id' => 'catid'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'batchno')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['catid'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select BatchNo',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/production/productbatch/subcat'])
    ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'prodqty')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($productname, 'bottlename')->textInput() ?>




    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

The error I'm getting is - 
[image: Here]

Productnames Model -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\production\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "productnames".
 *
 * @property integer $productid
 * @property string $company
 * @property string $type
 * @property string $productnames_productname
 * @property integer $inventory
 * @property string $unitrmcost
 * @property string $unitlabelcost
 * @property string $unitcartonecost
 * @property string $productnames_labelname
 * @property string $productnames_cartonename
 * @property string $bottletype
 * @property string $captype
 *
 * @property Productbatch[] $productbatches
 * @property Production[] $productions
 * @property Bottlename $bottletype0
 * @property Capname $captype0
 * @property Cartonename $productnamesCartonename
 * @property Labelname $productnamesLabelname
 * @property Productsales[] $productsales
 */
class Productnames extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'productnames';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['company', 'type', 'productnames_productname'], 'required'],
            [['inventory'], 'integer'],
            [['company'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['type', 'unitrmcost', 'unitlabelcost', 'unitcartonecost'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['productnames_productname', 'productnames_labelname', 'productnames_cartonename'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['bottletype', 'captype'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['productnames_productname'], 'unique']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'productid' => 'Productid',
            'company' => 'Company',
            'type' => 'Type',
            'productnames_productname' => 'Productnames Productname',
            'inventory' => 'Inventory',
            'unitrmcost' => 'Unitrmcost',
            'unitlabelcost' => 'Unitlabelcost',
            'unitcartonecost' => 'Unitcartonecost',
            'productnames_labelname' => 'Productnames Labelname',
            'productnames_cartonename' => 'Productnames Cartonename',
            'bottletype' => 'Bottletype',
            'captype' => 'Captype',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductbatches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productbatch::className(), ['productname' => 'productnames_productname']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Production::className(), ['productname' => 'productnames_productname']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getBottletype0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Bottlename::className(), ['bottlename' => 'bottletype']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCaptype0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Capname::className(), ['capname' => 'captype']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductnamesCartonename()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Cartonename::className(), ['cartone_name' => 'productnames_cartonename']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductnamesLabelname()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Labelname::className(), ['label_name' => 'productnames_labelname']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductsales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productsales::className(), ['productname' => 'productnames_productname']);
    }
}
```

Comment: show you related controllerAction and view

Comment: I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: can you show your `Productnames` model code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to render `productname` to create view, so pass it.

```
       return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'bottle' => $bottle,
            'productname' => $productname,
        ]);
```

Comment: I've added 'productname' => $productname, in render. But still the same error. I've added my productnames Model

Comment: you also  pass to  `Production _form` view?

Comment: I've already given production _form in the question as it is.

Comment: I have say to pass `'productname' => $productname` to `Production _form`.

Comment: Ohh! I got you. Now it's working. Sorry about that. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's variants. Either you use two model instances(current and related) and pass them to view http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html or add virtual attribute to current model http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html.

Comment: This is a very useful piece of document.

Answer (score 0):

you have use `$model = new Production();` in view ..so you have to define productname in production class .like--

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [           
        'productname' => 'Product Name',
    ];
}
```

then check it ...